# DropDownList binding with table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have ASP.NET MVC app with table, which contains flats (address, date added, comment).

In "create" and "edit" forms I want to use DropDownList eg. for flat type.

I have 1 table with all these flat properties (address etc.), second with flat types (id + name).

My question is how to bind dropdownlist with flat types table and then do proper relationships between these tables? Can I do this in one controller?

Summary:

I want to provide list with items from one table, insert proper Id value to basic table and connect them with Id-Id relation. Guess I can use only one @Html.Model in my Create/Edit views (this is my bassic problem)

Comment: Have you tried something so far? StackOverflow community usually feeds on code :)

Comment: I don't know how to use model "FlatType" in any view, when I have to use also fields from "Flat" model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't bind your component (dropdownlist) to the table in the database.

MVC is a design pattern where data is passed through different layers, gaining in clarity and code efficiency.

Your business Model (the M in MVC) will have to implement a method to load data from database. You can use Linq2Sql, you can execute directly your queries through a database connection or use whatever system you prefer.

This means that when your system reacts to a petition, usually with a Controller calling to a View, if you want this View to load data into an object, you have to load it from database before passing it to the View.

So, your controller decides to call a View, your business Model identifies the information that will be needed on the View, and creates data structures that will be fetch to the View. Then, in the View, you just link your dropdownlist control to the data in the Model.

Usually SelectList type is one of the best options to link data through a DropDownList, although you can use almost any IEnumerable type.

TL;DR;:

- Read data from the database in your model, before calling the view.
- Build a SelectList and load it with this data.
- Pass the data to the View (tip: it can be part of a greater data structure).
- Link the DropDownList component to the SelectList passed into the View Model.

Comment: thanks for info, but I have 1 more question. In my ViewModel I've got List<FlatType> and IQueryable<Flat>. How should I declarate Flat to get access to any field of Flat table in my view?

Comment: If you pass a IQueryable<Flat> object to your view, through return View(yourObject), you can access this object on rendering time in the view with Model.yourObjectAttributes, which means that if yourObject is a IQueryable object you can loop through Model object on View. Of course, you need to load database info on yourObject before returning it to the View.